# Add dynamic watermark that randomly changes position over video React/Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video-watermarking

I am building an online course website. To discourage video recording of paid courses, I would like to add a dynamic watermark over the video which randomly changes location over the screen. The watermark will display the email id of the user logged in. Is there a way to do this using React / Node JS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For media manipulation you can use use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) library. In the following demo i used [ffmpeg node wrapper](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg).

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const PORT = 3000;
const VIDEO_PATH = 'big_buck_bunny.mp4';
const WATERMARK_PATH = `${__dirname}/watermark-128.png`;

const videoHandler = (req, res) => {
  new ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream(VIDEO_PATH))
    .input(WATERMARK_PATH)
    .complexFilter("overlay='x=if(eq(mod(n\\,18)\\,0)\\,sin(random(1))*w\\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\\,18)\\,0)\\,sin(random(1))*h\\,y)'")
    .outputOptions('-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov')
    .toFormat('mp4')
    .pipe(res, {end: true});
};

const server = http.createServer(videoHandler);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```